# How to get metadata from Media objects

Tags: java, javafx, metadata

I am trying to make a mp3 player in JavaFX and so far have gotten it to load songs and play, but now I want to display the metadata from the Media object to a tableview. I have a song class which acts as a model class and in my controller class I have a Label I am testing to see if I can get the metadata to display, but it always comes as null.

```
package application;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Song {
private File file;
private String title;
private String artist;
private String album;
private Media music;
private MediaPlayer mp;

public Song(File file) {
    music = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
    mp = new MediaPlayer(music);
    getMeta();
    artist = (String) mp.getMedia().getMetadata().get("artist");
    title = (String) music.getMetadata().get("title");
    album = (String) music.getMetadata().get("album");
    //artist = "test";
    //album = "test";
    //title = "test";
}


public void play() {
    mp.play();
}

public void pause() {
    mp.pause();
}

public void stop() {
    mp.stop();
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public String getArtist(){
    return artist;
}

public String getAlbum(){
    return album;
}





}
```

In my controller class

```
// Event Listener on Button[#loadBtn].onAction
@FXML
public void loadFile(ActionEvent event) {
    Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
    Window theStage = source.getScene().getWindow();
    //set fileChooser filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("MP3 files", "*.mp3");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
    fileChooser.setTitle("Select MP3 files");
    //File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(theStage);
    //mySong = new Song(file);
    list = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(theStage);
    if(list!=null){
        for(File x: list) {
            mySong = new Song(x);
        }
    }
    label.setText(mySong.getTitle());
}
```

In the last line I am testing if the metadata was retrieved correctly and it is always null. I have the label to be set as initially to say "test" so I would know if it was making any changes and it does, but not to what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html) (my emphasis):

> Information about the media such as duration, metadata, tracks, and video resolution may be obtained from a Media instance. **The media information is obtained asynchronously and so not necessarily available immediately after instantiation of the class.** All information should however be available if the instance has been associated with a MediaPlayer and that player has transitioned to MediaPlayer.Status.READY status. To be notified when metadata or Tracks are added, observers may be registered with the collections returned by getMetadata()and getTracks(), respectively.

So you can do something like this:

```
public Song(File file) {
    music = new Media(file.toURI().toString());

    music.getMetadata().addListener((Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> c) -> {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            if ("artist".equals(c.getKey())) {
                artist = c.getValueAdded().toString();
            } else if ("title".equals(c.getKey())) {
                title = c.getValueAdded().toString();
            } else if ("album".equals(c.getKey())) {
                album = c.getValueAdded().toString();
            }
        }
    });

    mp = new MediaPlayer(music);

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it still appears to not work, only reason I can think is maybe my mp3 files don't have metadata? 
http://imgur.com/a/F4xQx
But it looks like it does

Comment: You can try `if (c.wasAdded()) { System.out.println(c.getKey() + " : " + c.getValueAdded()) }` to see if there's any metadata being picked up at all. If you have a hex editor, you can open the MP3 file with it and see if you can see [ID3 tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) in there.

Comment: Ok so it is picking up the meta data in the "song" class, but when I run 
'code'System.out.println("song title: "+mySong.getArtist());'code'
in the controller class it outputs "song title: null"
in the song class it outputs "artist:Foo Fighters
album:Saint Cecilia EP
title:Saint Cecilia"
any ideas why the get methods are giving nulls?

Comment: @JohnSmith Presumably because you are calling `mySong.getArtist()` before the artist property is set...? Use JavaFX properties in the `Song` class for `artist`, `title`, and `album` and then bind the label's text to those properties.

Comment: That actually was it, I was running the print line at the wrong spot, but it actually works. Thanks so much!