# MetaData recovery java

Tags: java, listener, metadata

I'm trying to recover the metaData of different media files but for some reason my method is not executing the code in the right order. The metaData is recovered correctly but the return value is *null* because the method is not executing in order. Here's the code:

```
public String getMetadata(ObservableList<Media> mediaList, int track){

    mediaList.get(track).getMetadata().addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> ch) -> {
        System.out.println("1");
        String key = ch.getKey(); 
        Object value = ch.getValueAdded();
        if (ch.wasAdded()) {                
            switch (key) {
                case "title":
                    Ptitle = value.toString();
                    System.out.println("2"+Ptitle);
                    break;
                case "artist":
                    Partist = value.toString();
                    System.out.println("3" + Partist);
                    break;
                case "album":
                    Palbum = value.toString();
                    System.out.println("4" + Palbum);
                    break;  
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println("1" + Ptitle + " " + Partist + " " + Palbum);
    });

    System.out.println("2" + Ptitle + " " + Partist + " " + Palbum);
    return Ptitle;
}
```

It's executing this: 

`System.out.println("2" + Ptitle + " " + Partist + " " + Palbum);
return Ptitle;`

before anything else..

So this is the [returned value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q38sH.png). The blue circle is what's getting returned and the red one is what should be returned, but since one task is getting executed before the other it's not working properly.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143756/how-to-get-metadata-from-media-objects

Comment: Didn't work... Because I'm trying to display a playlist before transforming my media into a mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code

```
mediaList.get(track).getMetadata().addListener...
```

will be execute asynchronously so it might not be available immediately. That explains why that piece of code is executed before anything else

Comment: So I told myself, I tried using a Thread.sleep() so it could take it's time executing but it still chose to execute the second half first.. Any thoughts on how I could solve it?

Comment: A listener could happen at any time. MapChangeListener.Change could be called several times as well. You could put your listener inside a loop but you could loop forever if the listener never gets called

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Getalbumartisttitle.htm

Comment: Adding a loop does make it loop forever, I tried that already.. As for the solution, it's almost what I have but my code is separated into more than one class in order to make it more clear. It works if I apply it on one song and if I put everything in one class but the second I add another song and I want to display both in a list, all goes down the drain.

Comment: which media format are you trying to get the metadata?

Comment: MP3 files, but recovering them isn't the problem, it recovers the metadata correctly but everything else is already executed so the first value is null

Comment: I tried making another method that recovers the information after the `getMetadata()` method is executed but it didn't work either

Comment: what if you do something like. After the method signature declare a variable say count = 0. Insie the listener increase the count variable. Add a while(count ==0) loop before you return the value.

Comment: I tired that but the listener was never called and the loop just kept on going.

Comment: I read somewhere that MP3 files couldn't have the metadata extracted somewhere. Have you checked for the supported formats?

Comment: You can look at it now.